# Replace React Native Expo Splash Screen Image with Real Splash Screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, splash-screen

How to Replace React-Native Splash Image With Some Custom React-Native Page. Currently I'm using an image as splash screen. I want the splash screen to be dynamic and load/display some data from server. Here is my configuration of `app.json`:

```json
{
  "expo": {
  "name": "SplashDemo",
  "slug": "SplashDemo",
  "privacy": "public",
  "sdkVersion": "31.0.0",
  "platforms": [
    "ios",
    "android"
  ],
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
  "splash": {
    "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.sample.splash",
      "versionCode": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Primary focus on the splash configurations given as:

```json
"splash": {
  "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
  "resizeMode": "contain",
  "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
}
```

Can we somehow replace it with the React-Native page? How?

Comment: Have you got any solution for this